# Trigger function after update complete

Tags: javascript, sapui5, treetable

How can I perform the functions order, when the update function works with xsodata?! So far my problem is with updating the tree table and then open the previous rows that has been opened before update. I am using the setTimeout function but i know it is actually not the answer to this problem.

```
tEvents.unbindAggregation("rows");
tEvents.bindAggregation("rows",{
    path: "events>/prg_years(ID_SCENARIO=" + filterKRVR.scenario + ",I_YEAR=" + filterKRVR.year + "m)" + "/HisGTO",
    parameters: {
        navigation: {
            'prg_gto':  "HisPIPE",
            'prg_pipe': "HisKS",
            'prg_ks':   "HisLK"
        },
    }
}); 

tEvents.getModel('events').refresh();

        

if(bookmark.gto!==null){
    var that = this;
    setTimeout(function(){
        var t = that.getView().byId('eventsKRVR');
        t.expand(bookmark.gto);
    },800)
}
if(bookmark.pipe!==null){
    var that = this;
    setTimeout(function(){
        var t = that.getView().byId('eventsKRVR');
        t.expand(bookmark.pipe);
    },1500)
}
if(bookmark.ks!==null){
    var that = this;
    setTimeout(function(){
        var t = that.getView().byId('eventsKRVR');
        t.expand(bookmark.ks);
    },2500)
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try to attach a event handler on the model using ```attachRequestCompleted(callbackFn)``` ? Make sure to attach the handler only once.

Comment: @newBee yes, i tried to attach on complete, didnt help...

Comment: In your question you say "before **update**" and talk about an odata service but in your code you use the ```refresh``` method which is used to fore an update of the UI controls. Do you really just want to refresh the bindings or trigger a backend call and actually change the Model content?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i managed to solve this question by `attachRequestCompleted`.

```
tEvents.getModel('events').attachRequestCompleted(function (oEvent) {
                    var url = oEvent.mParameters.url;
                    if(url.indexOf('prg_years') >= 0){
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            that.doRefresh();
                            setTimeout(function(){
                                tEvents.expand(bookmark.gto);
                            },100)
                        },100)
                    }else if(url.indexOf('prg_gto') >= 0){
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            that.doRefresh();
                            setTimeout(function(){
                                tEvents.expand(bookmark.pipe);
                            },100)
                        },100)
                    }else if(url.indexOf('prg_pipe') >= 0){
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            that.doRefresh();
                            setTimeout(function(){
                                tEvents.expand(bookmark.ks);
                            },100)
                        },100)
                    }else if(url.indexOf('prg_ks') >= 0){
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            that.doRefresh();
                            setTimeout(function(){
                                $('.sapUiScrollBar div').scrollTop(32*bookmark.lk-64);
                            },100)
                        },1000)
                    }
                });
```

also made a hack for table refresh, because sometimes there is a problem with rendering the tables, i asked this question here: [Bug after update TreeTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35197927/bug-after-update-treetable)